# identity of polylogarithm

Tags: sequences-and-series

let be the function defined by a series

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}g(n)x^{n} $$

assume also that $ g(n)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a(k)n^{k} $

then we have the double series

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a(k)n^{k}x^{n} $$

if we interchange the order of summation and make the sum over 'n' plus zeta regularization with the polylogarithm $ Li _{s}(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n}}{n^{s}} $

we find $$ f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a(k)Li_{-k}(x) $$

if the number of 'k' is limited so the infinite series is finite we can evaluate always $ f(x) $ by using a finite sum of terms $ Li_{-k}(x) $ for k = 0,1,2,3, N $

are my calculations correct ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are correct. It should be noted, however, that polylogarithms of negative orders are elementary functions. In fact, one doesn't need to know anything about polylogarithms, it suffices to differentiate geometric series an appropriate number of times:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^kx^n=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=
\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^k\frac{1}{1-x}.$$
So, for example,
$$\mathrm{Li}_{-2}(x)=\left(x\frac{d}{dx}\right)^2\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3}.$$